# How to execute a script.sh using cron?

Tags: 18.04, bash, cron, gnome-shell

I have a script.sh which consists of few commands and I want that script to be executed using cron.

Currently am executing manually by **bash script.sh** and I have given a job like below

> 40 12 * * * /bin/bash -c /home/local/user/Documents/script.sh

This doesn't execute the script. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does `/var/log/cron` say. There should be a line or more for the execution at 12:40.

Comment: Do not have any such file named like cron @SorenA and thank you for the response mate

Comment: `cron` logs to `/var/log/syslog`. Do `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` and see what happens around that time.

Comment: do not have access to it and so the above way is correct to execute isn't it?

Comment: If you do have a `/home/local/user` directory, it might be correct. But that is not standard.

Comment: Also not having access to `/var/log/syslog` is not standard. That file should be readable by anyone in the `adm` group, which by default contains the first user.

Comment: How did you create that cronjob? What does `ls -l /home/local/user/Documents/script.sh` show?

Answer (score 2):

Run:

```
crontab -e
```

And then try shortening paths and commands:

```
40 12 * * * bash ~/Documents/script.sh
```